# Apply same width to child divs as parent div

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint

i have one div which contains several divs. I changed the parent div width. But because of the divs which are children to the parent div, the width is increasing. i written the css class like this.

```
$('#s4-workspace').css({
    'width': '900px'
});
```

Here `s4-workspace` is the parent div. 
After applying the above property and when I see in the IE, the width is increasing to 1600px. I want to apply this width to all the child divs. Is there any method to achieve such functionality in jquery?

i am working in sharepoint designer.

Comment: How about doing it with css? Like width: 100% or display: block?

Comment: Thats not working. All ready tried

Comment: Maybe you can use jsfiddle to show the issue? Cuz it's bad design to set width with js for it's the css's job.

Comment: Yes that is good suggestion. But I am doing for sharepoint Master page in sharepoint designer. I am not able to show that entire page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/) jquery function to set the width by getting children using **[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)** function.

```
$('#s4-workspace').children().width($('#s4-workspace').width());
```

Its better to handle it with style sheet instead jquery/javascript. Setting width of children in percentage could do it, like 100%.

Answer (score 3):

of course, if any of those children have borders, or padding, or are floated alongside other floats, this approach won't work. have you identified *why* those child elements are sizing to 1600?

Comment: No.. I am unable to find that.

Comment: are you using a browser such as chrome, with a built-in web inspector? or Firefox, in which case you can check out firebug? these tools will tell you what styles are being applied to which elements - essential for CSS debugging.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to find there only. But the width is showing to child divs. I dont know why even though i applied in the .js file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're saying. Your web inspector should tell you whether a style is being applied because it's been set in a stylesheet (amongst other things, you should see a selector alongside it) or whether it's been applied via the element's style attribute (which is what .css() does). In the latter case, it will be listed inside an 'element.style' block, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

the `width:100%;` will work fine